# tshark command line to convert a wireskark pcap file to a text file

Tags: pcap

I am trying to use tshark command line to convert a wireskark pcap file to a text file. everything looks right. But I get no output and no errors

```
public void convertPcapToTxt( )  {
  try {
    // setting output and input file names
    String resultfile = "C:\\MY.txt";
    String pcapfile = "C:\\MY.pcap";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // create output
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(resultfile);
    // set command line
    Process proc = rt.exec("tshark.exe -V -r " + pcapfile);
    //output to file
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader
                             (new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
     String s = null;
     while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      out.println(s);
     }
   //close output
   out.close();
   } catch (IOException io) {
      io.printStackTrace();
   } 
}
```

Comment: What gets printed if you try the command "tshark.exe -v" (lower-case "v")?  If *that* prints nothing, perhaps it's not finding the TShark executable.

Comment: when I run this command from the command line it runs fine "tshark.exe -V -r C:\MY.pcap" so it is finding the tshark and displaying it to my screen. I can even do "tshark.exe -V -r C:\MY.pcap > C:\MY.txt"; and get a good text file. I have tried hard coding it in java and still get no output or error

Comment: also just a fyi. I have this same code working but with the commands to convert the pcap to xml. and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void convertPcapToTxt(File file, String pcapfile) {
  try {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String commands = "tshark.exe -V -r \"" + pcapfile + "\"";
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader
                             (new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(s);
    }
    out.close();
  } catch (IOException io) {
     io.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: to convert pcap to XML. replace -V with "-T pdml"